# a question about a ring (unit, multiplicative inverse)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

S is the power set of integers Z.
Define two binary operations:
$\bigoplus $: $A$\bigoplus $B=(A\bigcup B)-(A\bigcap B)$, the symmetric difference set
$\ast : A \ast B = A \bigcap B$,
which forms a ring.

Q: Does $\ast$ have a unit?

I'm even wondering will the multiplicative identity is Z ?? it feels so weird....
And what would the inverse of an element of S looks like?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: What are $\varnothing\oplus A$ and $\Bbb Z\cap A$? And what is $A\oplus A$?

Comment: $\varnothing\oplus A$=A, $\Bbb Z\cap A$=A, $A\oplus A$=$\varnothing$

Comment: so the multiplicative identity is really Z?

Comment: @Lily: Right, so there you have your additive and multiplicative identities and your additive inverses. Yes, the mult. ident. really is $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: thank you for the hint. i see. so the additive identity is $\varnothing$, multiplicative identities is Z, and additive inverses is the element itself. What would the multiplicative inverse look like then? I don't think there's an element is a unit, right?

Comment: @Lily: That’s right on all counts, except that $\Bbb Z$ itself is a multiplicative unit — the only one, in fact. This is clear, because if $A\ne\Bbb Z$, then $A\cap X\subseteq A$, and therefore $A\cap X\ne\Bbb Z$, so that $A$ has no mult. inverse.